# Limilabs IMAP exception

Tags: imap

I am trying to use Limilabs imap library to connect to email;

```
  tcpc = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("imap.gmail.com", 993);
```

works fine ;  while  limilabs imap does not

```
using (Imap imap = new Imap())
{
    imap.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993);
```

gives exception :

```
Limilabs.Client.ServerException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Tried to read a line. No data received. Please make sure that antivirus and firewall software are disabled or configured correctly.
  Source=Mail
  StackTrace:
       at   .()
       at   .(MemoryStream )
       at   .()
       at Limilabs.Client.IMAP.ImapResponse.(Stream )
       at Limilabs.Client.IMAP.Imap.(ImapResponse )
       at Limilabs.Client.IMAP.Imap.(String , Boolean )
       at Limilabs.Client.IMAP.Imap.ReceiveResponse(String tag)
       at Limilabs.Client.IMAP.Imap.wqf45mzzsju7786nbrb2h8aclqm8jmnx    ()
       at Limilabs.Client.ClientBase.Connect(String host, Int32 port, Boolean useSSL)
       at Limilabs.Client.ClientBase.Connect(String host, Int32 port)
       at ConsoleIMAP.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\hmohamed\WcfServiceLibrary1\ConsoleIMP\Program.cs:line 136
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message=Tried to read a line. No data received.
       Source=Mail
       StackTrace:
            at   .()
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Let me guess, Limilabs expects to speak IMAP without TLS, gmail expects IMAP with TLS, and as a result none of them ever speak to each other?

Comment: so can i try hotmail!

Comment: tried connectssl  but it times out

Answer (score 2):

Limilabs imap.Connect has an overload to specify if SSL is to be used. It does not infer it from the port you specify. You can also use the imap.ConnectSSL method.

For more info, see:
http://www.limilabs.com/blog/use-ssl-with-imap

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is 2 years old, but it may be important for someone else having this problem.

Imap.Connect/Imap.ConnectSSL methods not only connect, they also start TLS/SSL negotiation (if needed), receive initial server response, and get extensions supported by IMAP server.

That's why connecting with TcpClient may look like it's working at first, but in fact, you haven't started TLS/SSL negotiation nor any other communication with the server.

Gmail supports TLS/SSL connections only, so you must use ConnectSSL method, there is also no need to specify port explicitly:

```
using (Imap imap = new Imap())
{
    imap.ConnectSSL("imap.gmail.com");

    //...

    imap.Close()
}
```

Remember that you must [enable IMAP access for your account in Gmail](https://www.limilabs.com/blog/enable-imap-in-gmail).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, we just had the same error and solved it, hope can help anyone who has the same situation as us.

We use `Amazon Simple Email Service (SES)` and SES provides different ports: STARTTLS Port(25, 587 or 2587) and TLS Wrapper Port(465 or 2465)

In our code, we call `smtp.StartTLS()` after `smtp.Connect(Server, Port)`, we should use the port STARTTLS Port(25, 587 or 2587), if we use TLS Wrapper Port(465 or 2465) will raise the error:

`Tried to read a line. Only '' received. Please make sure that antivirus and firewall software are disabled or configured correctly.`